# not able to open spring default hal browser or any other resource inside jar in tomcat if unpackwar is set to false

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Hi I am using spring data rest provided HAL browser to view my spring data rest HAL based api .So far things have been good when I am running it via eclipse or as a spring boot app for testing in my local .Though when I deploy on aws on a tomcat container (as a spring boot war) I get this weird error as below when I browse to the roor or the address of the hal browser /browser/index.html#

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Aug 24 07:05:46 UTC 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Jar URL cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: war:jar:file:/deployment/wars/hfds.1.3.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-hal-browser-2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am still not able to find a valid justification on why its not being able to find the provided hal browser though things work fine in local .Am I missing something can someone please help .Is this a bug with spring framework or otherwise

**UPDATE**

This seems to be an environment specific issue as in windows environmnet I get the url file:/.... whil ein linux I get war:jar:file which causes the issue due to this code section in org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils

```
public static File getFile(URL resourceUrl, String description) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Assert.notNull(resourceUrl, "Resource URL must not be null");
    if (!URL_PROTOCOL_FILE.equals(resourceUrl.getProtocol())) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
                description + " cannot be resolved to absolute file path " +
                "because it does not reside in the file system: " + resourceUrl);
    }
    try {
        return new File(toURI(resourceUrl).getSchemeSpecificPart());
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
        // Fallback for URLs that are not valid URIs (should hardly ever happen).
        return new File(resourceUrl.getFile());
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you deploy it to a local Tomcat container?

Comment: Hi @andy-wilkinson in local it works fine (I meant on tomcat with oas as windows) . Also if I debug the path comes out fine with description as Jar url and path is file:/C:/ebcidic/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-hal-browser-2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar which works with the code whereas in ec2 linux path is like war:jar:file:/deployment/war/xyz.war!//WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-rest-hal-browser-2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar so the war:jar causes an issue it seems

Comment: @AndyWilkinson any idea what shall be causing this or I am missing something

Comment: I'd guess that the Tomcat instance is configured not to unpack the war file when it's deployed. Something related to the HAL browser, I can't tell what from the information you've provided, can't cope with that so it fails.

Comment: yes @AndyWilkinson ,the unpackwar was false (on the ec2 instance) for my config which seems to cause the hal browser not to be found from the war .Doing the same in local replicates the issue whereas when I set unpack to true on ec2 things work :).Is this a bug or using hal browser (or resources *html inside a jar) mandates unpackwar to be set as true always ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi so with the help of Andy finally figured out that the workaround is to set unpackwar to true to make the HAL browser work .Not sure this is a mandate yet so have raised an issue for spring boot at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3826 to look further .But as of now setting upackwar=true works just fine .

**UPDATE**

This has been fixed in the 4.2.2 and greater spring version via https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13393